# codeigniter removing index.php from url in wamp

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, url

I have big problem trying to remove index.php from url's

i have searched lots if forums (this also), but no help for my situation.

so i have config.php file

```
$config['base_url'] = '';
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';
```

my .htaccess file in public_html folder near index.php

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /public_html/

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

and in WAMP apache (ver.: 2.4.9) i have rewrite_module ON (and it's working)
and my httpd.conf AllowOverride set to All

so when i am going to mydomain.com/controller/action - I get 404
but when i go to mydomain.com/index.php/controller/action - everything is OK..

i have tried lots of .htaccess examples... and so on.. nothing helps..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this htacess and then go to config.php and remove index.php

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options -Indexes
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: still nothing.. getting "The requested URL WayTillMyProject/public_html/index.php/admin/dashboard/modal was not found on this server."

Comment: I see you have nothing in your base url try adding your url in there. and add url helper make sure routes are set correct. `$route['perferdname'] = folder/controller/index` or `$route['perferdname'] = controller/index`

Comment: now it's redirecting to CI errors/index.php for 404 error

Comment: Whats check your routes like below for each controller would need route

Comment: don't really know what you wanted to say/check
if you talking about routes.php file, i haven't change nothing there..

Comment: For each controller that you make you should add a new route in the routes file http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/routing.html

Comment: well i am pretty confused of it.. :/ 
if i have url like 
`localhost/ci/index.php/admin/dashboard`
so how it should look? :// because i am trying lots of options, but still nothing happens when i remove index.php from URL..

Comment: Please watch these tutorials will give you a starting point https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9hRNFgSLLAQ

Comment: ok.. finally i have understand.. ://
i was having ci in my url and i needed RewriteBase /ci/
buti was doing it wrong because i was writing /public_html/ (i though it is folder name, not URL sublink or whatever it called)